# Can the Operating System access a particular filesystem after it has been unmounted?

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have mounted a filesystem at a particular directory and I replace a file present in the filesystem.I now unmount the filesystem. Is there any possibility of Operating system accessing the replaced file present in the filesystem?

Comment: Are you asking if the system can still access the filesystem after it's been unmounted? If so, then yes, in a coarse way, for example with `dd`.

Comment: sorry i meant the operating system

Answer (score 1):

If the system has access to the underlying block device, yes, in theory you could read the filesystem files, but! this is cumbersome, and can cause more problems than it's worth, specially if you try to write it. In short, yes, if a OS have access to the block device it's always possible they can read specific files if they know their position in the partition.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand, If the question is:

> could some process have keep an acces to my file after umout ?

, then the answer is no, as you can't umount if someone/something access your file.